# OAuth signature does not match

Tags: wp-api

I am using the below in my wordpress for developing a oauth based application.

**WP-API** (api generating plugin)

**WP API OAuth1** (oauth server)and

**WP API client-cli** (oauth client library)

at the below url is for the wp client-cli
https://man-sudarshann-1.c9.io/api/

I am getting this error **OAuth signature does not match** when I click the AUTH button for autherizing the request. I have tried all the fixed for this over the internet. but none helped

signature generated and sent from api client is **3ko8DUsUUEB4Hqaks68vGYnTjQM=**

signature generated in server side is  **5rPsul6zplhfNvb4o+Mz11O/OyI=**

so the below code is failing

```
if ( ! hash_equals( $signature, $consumer_signature ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'json_oauth1_signature_mismatch', __( 'OAuth signature does not match' ), array( 'status' => 401 ) );
}
```

I guess the API console is generating wrong signature. Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: put single quotation marks around the values for $signature and $consumer_signature

Comment: sorry I actually I just put them for reference not as code. these values are calculated but algorithms in javascript clients and server side

Comment: I selected x-www-form-urlencoded from Body section (for request) in Postman, and it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue when trying to use Client-CLI with OAuth 1.0a plugin, however I found a solution [here](https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1/pull/32) on the official repository.

In the file `lib/class-wp-json-authentication-oauth1.php` on line `524`, change the following code:

```
$base_request_uri = rawurlencode( get_home_url( null, parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH ), 'http' ) );
```

to:

```
$home_url_path = parse_url(get_home_url (null,'','http'), PHP_URL_PATH );
$request_uri_path = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH );
if (substr($request_uri_path, 0, strlen($home_url_path)) == $home_url_path) {
    $request_uri_path = substr($request_uri_path, strlen($home_url_path));
}
$base_request_uri = rawurlencode( get_home_url( null, $request_uri_path, 'http' ) );
```

This should solve the problem you are facing.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on how this works exactly? What changed? I don't know PHP but I'm running into the same issue with a javascript client I'm writing, and I think perhaps your solution might generalize to my app.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that signature request is handled correctly:
http://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Signing.html

If you're using POSTMAN you can set it to OAuth 1.0 under Authorization and then select the options

- Add empty params to signature
- Encode OAuth signature
- Save helper data to request

Here's a detailed tutorial I wrote on using OAuth 1 and Postman with WordPress: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/239873/51201

Comment: "Add empty params to signature" worked for me. I don't really understand the reason behind it.

Comment: @LocPham it's because the signature is generated from the query arguments, thus, you need to have empty arguments included to have it generate the signature correctly

Comment: I have problem in installing and activating plugins with wordpress 4.9.6. would you check this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/300120/141031

Answer (score 2):

In Postman under **Authorization** try deselecting "**Add params to header**".

Comment: not sure why this got downvoted, worked for me...

Comment: Worked here too!

Answer (score 0):

check you baseurl forwarding. 
In my case the non-www was being forwarded to www. After updating the baseurl to www.example.com format it worked for me.